# error in module-info.java file in javafx project

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, desktop-application

I have been using javaFX for a while now, but a day ago when I crated a new project I noticed that there is a new file created automatically with the name (module-info.java) in the default package, and I can not even delete it!!.

[image]

the following code is written there:

```
module prog0 {
    requires javafx.controls;
    
    opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}
```

unfortunatily all lines has errors

1ST line : **Syntax error on token "module", interface expected**

2nd line : **Syntax error on token ".", , expected**

3rd line : **Multiple markers at this line

```
- Syntax error on token "to", = 
 expected

- Syntax error on token ".", , 
 expected

- Syntax error on token "to", = 
 expected

- Syntax error on token ".", , 
 expected**
```

Libraries used:
[image]

Comment: That `JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]` line is likely the problem.  Java 1.5 does not know what a module descriptor is.  Remove that library from your project.

Comment: Finally, it is working, Thanks a lot.

Comment: "_and I can not even delete it_" – I find that strange, given having a module descriptor is not a requirement, even for JavaFX applications.

Comment: I worked with javaFX for some time, and I never used a module file before. that is the first time I see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module-info.java file looks pretty typical for modular Java projects (Java 9+). It is usual to require the javafx.controls, and to open your application (here, actually named "application") to javafx. I think this latter statement pertains to the javafx module needing to be able to look into the module that has the entry point for the program.

But the location of the file seems suspect to me. I'm not up on all the complexities, but I do think the file would be better located directly under the /src directory rather than in a default package. Usually the module-info.java file is the top file folder level and the source code for the program is a child folder.

In other words, the module-info.java file and the /application package file should be in the same folder. At least, that is how things are set up on my javafx programs and modular java programs.

EDIT: I noticed that your Build Path is listing Java 1.5! This Java doesn't support modules. Modules were introduced in Java 9.

Comment: I tried to relocate it in the same package (Application), directly under (src) folder, and even just in the proj0 file with the application package, but unfortunately nothing changed and the errors are still there

Comment: also I was using JFX for some time befor, and I have never scene the module-info file before \!!

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that you are using Java 1.5. Can that be true? You need to have at least Java 9 in order to properly make use of the modules.

Comment: I tried that and it worked, Thank you so much

Comment: Eclipse (I think this is Eclipse) likely just labels anything directly under `src` as being in the "default package", as that's where said default package is "located". But yes, the module descriptor belongs under the root of the source directory (here `src`, using Maven/Gradle it'd be under `src/main/java`).

Comment: It would probably be good to mark this question solved. IDK that the answer is clear, though, since it is hidden in a comment (about Java 1.5 not being modular). Should I add that to the main answer as an edit to make it more clear to people who might use this as a reference? I think the intended mission of StackOverflow is to function as a helpful reference guide, first and foremost.

Comment: Thanks for adding that, the question is marked as solved

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the JavaFX library under **Modulepath** as a **user Library**. so the problem will go away.  [see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt1nI.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).